# Unknown type 'processDefinition' within FormService

Tags: grails, groovy, activiti

We are currently writing a new front-end to Activiti using Grails, to present the user with a customised UI when handling tasks and filling in associated data.

We are able to query the Activiti Engine and return a list of tasks; the following code is working as we'd expect and (along with the view) giving a basic list of tasks - name, description, etc:

```
def index() {
    def tasks = activitiService.findAllTasks(["sort": null, "offset": 0, "max": 10])
    [tasks: tasks]
}
```

However, when we try and pull back the form data for an individual task (so we can display the form to the user for completion):

```
def view(params) {

    def taskQuery = taskService.createTaskQuery()
    def task = taskQuery.taskId(params.id).singleResult();
    def form = formService.getRenderedTaskForm(params.id)

    [task: task, form: form]
}
```

an error is being thrown:

```
unknown type 'processDefinition' processDefinition
```

on the `def form =` line; the full trace is:

```
    Line | Method
->>   55 | parseFormPropertyType             in org.activiti.engine.impl.form.FormTypes
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|     61 | parseConfiguration                in org.activiti.engine.impl.form.DefaultFormHandler
|     34 | parseConfiguration . . . . . . .  in org.activiti.engine.impl.form.DefaultStartFormHandler
|     84 | createStartFormHandlers           in org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.parser.handler.StartEventParseHandler
|     58 | executeParse . . . . . . . . . .  in     ''
|     38 | executeParse                      in     ''
|     84 | parse . . . . . . . . . . . . . . in org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.parser.handler.AbstractBpmnParseHandler
|     27 | parse                             in org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.parser.handler.AbstractFlowNodeBpmnParseHandler
|     36 | parse . . . . . . . . . . . . . . in org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.parser.handler.AbstractActivityBpmnParseHandler
|     73 | parseElement                      in org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.parser.BpmnParseHandlers
|    435 | processFlowElements . . . . . . . in org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.parser.BpmnParse
|     88 | transformProcess                  in org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.parser.handler.ProcessParseHandler
|     49 | executeParse . . . . . . . . . .  in     ''
|     35 | executeParse                      in     ''
|     84 | parse . . . . . . . . . . . . . . in org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.parser.handler.AbstractBpmnParseHandler
|     73 | parseElement                      in org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.parser.BpmnParseHandlers
|    395 | transformProcessDefinitions . . . in org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.parser.BpmnParse
|    231 | execute                           in     ''
|    107 | deploy . . . . . . . . . . . . .  in org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.deployer.BpmnDeployer
|     50 | deploy                            in org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.deploy.DeploymentManager
|    115 | resolveProcessDefinition . . . .  in     ''
|     65 | findDeployedProcessDefinitionById in     ''
|    751 | getTaskDefinition . . . . . . . . in org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.TaskEntity
|     54 | execute                           in org.activiti.engine.impl.cmd.GetRenderedTaskFormCmd
|     24 | execute . . . . . . . . . . . . . in org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandInvoker
|     57 | execute                           in org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContextInterceptor
|     47 | doInTransaction . . . . . . . . . in org.activiti.spring.SpringTransactionInterceptor$1
|     45 | execute                           in org.activiti.spring.SpringTransactionInterceptor
|     31 | execute . . . . . . . . . . . . . in org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.LogInterceptor
|     40 | execute                           in org.activiti.engine.impl.cfg.CommandExecutorImpl
|     35 | execute . . . . . . . . . . . . . in     ''
|     46 | getRenderedTaskForm               in org.activiti.engine.impl.FormServiceImpl
|     22 | view . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  in TasksController.groovy
|    195 | doFilter                          in PageFragmentCachingFilter.java
|     63 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . . .  in AbstractFilter.java
|   1145 | runWorker                         in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    744 | run                               in java.lang.Thread
```

We appear to need to pass a process definition in to `formService` at some point, or at least have a library available that it can create one from; unfortunately, we've been unable to work out exactly how that can be done.

So - what have we missed that will get this working? Alternatively, are we actually going down the wrong route entirely and there's a better solution for what we need (short of querying the database tables directly, which we're trying to avoid)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this kind of error appears when you define a form field with a custom type that is not registered. If you are trying to display a form field that exposes your process definitions I've found a nice blog post that may be related [here](http://www.jorambarrez.be/blog/2013/03/13/creating-a-new-form-property-in-activiti/)

Basically you have to define your custom type (in this case `ProcessDefinitionFormType`) and register it in `resources.groovy`:

```
processDefinitionFormType(org.unnoware.ProcessDefinitionFormType)
processEngineConfiguration(org.activiti.spring.SpringProcessEngineConfiguration) {

           // ... many other properties are set here, you may copy them from activiti plugin source

            customFormTypes = [ref('processDefinitionFormType')]
        }
```

EDIT:

You can register your custom types in 'Config.groovy' too:

```
beans {
    processEngineConfiguration {
            customFormTypes = [new org.unnoware.ProcessDefinitionFormType()]
    }
}
```